# Can't derive some equivalences between regression coefficients formulas

Tags: regression-coefficients

I stumbled upon this set of equivalences between different formulas for $\beta$ : http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/d/d/0ddedb446f7520df577fcf48aa7012e2.png .
However I cannot go from the first step to the second one!

Here are my steps:

$\beta = \frac{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})²} \\
= \frac{\Sigma(x_iy_i-x_i\bar{y}-y_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}\bar{y})}{\Sigma(x_i²-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}²)} \\
= \frac{\Sigma x_iy_i-\Sigma x_i\bar{y}-\Sigma y_i\bar{x} + \Sigma\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\Sigma x_i²-2\Sigma x_i\bar{x}+\Sigma\bar{x}²} \\
= \frac{\Sigma x_iy_i-\frac{1}{n}\Sigma x_i\Sigma y_i-\frac{1}{n}\Sigma y_i\Sigma x_i + n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\Sigma x_i²-2\Sigma x_i\bar{x}+\frac{1}{n}(\Sigma x_i)²}$

So I actually get all the terms of the second formula from the picture at the numerator and denominator, but I have additional terms as well that I can't seem to cancel. If $\bar{x}$ could be assumed to be 0 it could remove the extra terms I have but afaik this is not a valid assumption in general (this formula should hold for non-centered data right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the final term in the numerator in your last step, $n\bar{x}\bar{y}$, this can be rewritten as $n \frac{1}{n}\sum{x_i} \frac{1}{n}\sum{y_i}$ so the $n$ cancels with one of the fractions an results in $\frac{1}{n}\sum{x_i}\sum{y_i}$  so now we have the same term in 3 places, once with a $+$ and twice with a $-$ so we can combine the positive with one of the negatives to get a 0 and drop those terms leaving only a negative one.

Similar for the denominator.